# Developer android OPENGL ES tutorial - black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to learn about opengl es and followed the tutorial att android developer. First one really small example - they said that the screen would turn to a grey color. When I replicated the example and launced the app om my Samsung galaxy SIII - the screen become totaly black and the action bar on the topscreen where the app-name can be seen. So - no error - just a black colour covering almost the whole screen except the actionbar.
Then on the extended example on developer android where shapes are supposed to be drawn - EXACTLY the same scenario - just a black screen - no errors.

I would like to know whats happening. I have followed the tutorial carefully

Its to much code to be shown here and the source can easily be downloaded here

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#manifest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my own experience I can tell you that there are better places to learn Opengl ES than android developer site. Firstly - they're telling you about the grey screen but actually they set a black clear color in their code:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

A grey color would be sth like this for example:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
```

Secondly, if you use emulator, make sure you have checked the "use host GPU" option while creating the virtual device.

Thirdly, you might have to attach this snippet of code before calling setRenderer(...) function:

```
super.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

As for the other places to learn OpenGL ES I strongly recommend this site: 
http://androidblog.reindustries.com/tutorials/

and a book: "Opengl Es 2.0 Programming Guide"

Comment: yes it worked - but i could not see the shapes. But I tried to mix arbitrary with the triangle coords - just ad hoc values, I changed from 0.0f to 0.3f - and wooops - i triangle was drawn on the screen. I thougt android's example would be 100%??? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing which you should be aware of - make sure that you **do not** initialize your shaders before the surface is created.